# Game of Life - Overwriting the current generation instead of updating to the next

Tags: python, pygame, iteration, python-3.7, conways-game-of-life

Below I have added my game of life code. The rules are defined correctly, and it runs smoothly. However, the game does not work as supposed. It is not updating to the next generation, but it seems to be overwriting the current generation. As an example:  Three horizontal dots are supposed to turn into three vertical dots in the next generation, but this does not happen.

The solution:
I have two generations, the current and the next generation. It has to apply the rules to the current generation and update them in the next generation. Then it has to overwrite the current generation with the next generation in one go, not cell by cell. How can I fix this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import itertools, os, platform, pygame, random

# Defining the grid dimensions.
GRID_SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750, 1000

# Defining the cell size and the number of cells in the X and Y direction.
CELL_SIZE = 10
X_CELLS = int(WIDTH/CELL_SIZE)
Y_CELLS = int(HEIGHT/CELL_SIZE)

# Defining the number and color for dead and living cells.
COLOR_DEAD = 0
COLOR_ALIVE = 1
colors = []
colors.append((0, 0, 0))  # Black
colors.append((0, 128, 128))  # blue

# Defining two lists: current generation and next generation.
current_generation = [[COLOR_DEAD for y in range(Y_CELLS)] for x in range(X_CELLS)]
next_generation = [[COLOR_DEAD for y in range(Y_CELLS)] for x in range(X_CELLS)]

# Defining the max frames per second/speed of the game.
FPS_MAX = 10

class GameOfLife:
    """
    describe what the method does.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # Initializing the interpreter and creating a root window and title.
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Game of Life - Created by - Have fun")
        # Defining the main frame, left-side frame and right-side frame.
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root , width=1000, height=1000, highlightbackground='red')
        self.menu = tk.Frame(self.frame, width=250, height=1000, highlightbackground='#595959', highlightthickness=10)
        self.game_border = tk.Frame(self.frame, width=750, height=1000, highlightbackground='green', highlightthickness=10)
        # Packing the windows.
        self.frame.pack()
        self.frame.pack_propagate(0)
        self.menu.pack(side="left")
        self.menu.pack_propagate(0)
        self.game_border.pack()

        # Defining the buttons.
        self.button_start = tk.Button(self.menu, text="Start", height=5, width=20, fg="black", activeforeground="red", background="grey80", activebackground="grey80", command=self.start_button)
        self.button_stop = tk.Button(self.menu, text="Stop", height=5, width=20, fg="black", activeforeground="red", background="grey80", activebackground="grey80", command=self.stop_button)
        self.button_iteration = tk.Button(self.menu, text="Next iteration", height=5, width=20, fg="black", activeforeground="red", background="grey80", activebackground="grey80", command=self.create_next_gen)
        self.button_random = tk.Button(self.menu, text="Random", height=5, width=20, fg="black", activeforeground="red", background="grey80", activebackground="grey80", command=self.random_grid)
        self.button_reset = tk.Button(self.menu, text="Reset", height=5, width=20, fg="black", activeforeground="red", background="grey80", activebackground="grey80", command=self.reset_button)
        self.button_quit = tk.Button(self.menu, text="Quit", height=5, width=20, fg="black", activeforeground="red", background="grey80", activebackground="grey80", command=self.quit_button)
        # Packing the buttons.
        self.button_start.pack()
        self.button_stop.pack()
        self.button_iteration.pack()
        self.button_random.pack()
        self.button_reset.pack()
        self.button_quit.pack()
        # Placing the buttons.
        self.button_start.place(x=40, y=50)
        self.button_stop.place(x=40, y=200)
        self.button_iteration.place(x=40, y=350)
        self.button_random.place(x=40, y=500)
        self.button_reset.place(x=40, y=650)
        self.button_quit.place(x=40, y=800)

        # Defining the slider.
        self.slider_random = tk.Scale(self.menu, from_=0, to=100, orient="horizontal", command=self.slider_value)
        self.slider_random.set(50)
        # Packing the slider.
        self.slider_random.pack()
        # Placing the slider.
        self.slider_random.place(x=62, y=590)

        # Defining a dropdown menu for the form and color.
        """
        self.options_figures = [
            "circles",
            "squares",
            "surprise"
        ]
        self.var_figure = tk.StringVar(self.root)
        self.dropdown_figure = tk.OptionMenu(self.menu, self.var_figure,
                                             self.options_figures[0], self.options_figures[1],
                                             self.options_figures[2])
        self.var_figure.set(self.options_figures[0])
        #self.var_color.trace("w", FUNCTIONNAME)
        self.dropdown_figure.pack()

        # Dropdown menu for the cell color
        self.options_colors = [
            "blue",
            "red",
            "white",
            "green",
            "yellow",
            "purple",
            "grey",
            "pink"
        ]
        self.var_color = tk.StringVar(self.root)
        self.dropdown_colors = tk.OptionMenu(self.menu, self.var_color,
                                             self.options_colors[0], self.options_colors[1],
                                             self.options_colors[2], self.options_colors[3],
                                             self.options_colors[4], self.options_colors[5],
                                             self.options_colors[6], self.options_colors[7])
        self.var_color.set(self.options_colors[0])
        #self.var_color.trace("w", FUNCTION NAME)
        self.dropdown_colors.pack()
        """

        # Defining the labels that count the dead and living cells.
        """
        self.label_alive = tk.Label(self.menu, text="Living cells:"+" 1000", height=5, width=20, fg="black", background="grey80")
        self.label_dead = tk.Label(self.menu, text="Dead cells"+" 1000", height=1, width=20, fg="black", background="grey80")
        Packing the labels
        self.label_alive.pack()
        self.label_dead.pack()
        self.label_alive.place(x=40, y=900)
        self.label_alive.place(x=40, y=900)
        """

        # This embeds the pygame window in the tkinter frame.
        os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(self.game_border.winfo_id())
        system = platform.system()
        if system == "Windows":
            os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
        elif system == "Linux":
            os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'x11'

        # Initializing pygame.
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(GRID_SIZE)
        # Initializing the generations.
        self.init_gen(current_generation, COLOR_DEAD)
        # Defining a clock to set the FPS.
        self.fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        # Setting variables for later use.
        self.next_iteration = False
        self.game_over = False

    # Get the slider value to change the % of randomness.
    def slider_value(self, value):
        self.value = value

    # Button functions.
    def start_button(self):
        self.next_iteration = True
    def stop_button(self):
        self.next_iteration = False
    def reset_button(self):
        self.next_iteration = False
        self.init_gen(next_generation, COLOR_DEAD)
    def quit_button(self):
        self.game_over = True

    # Initializing all the cells.
    def init_gen(self, generation, c):
        for y in range(Y_CELLS):
            for x in range(X_CELLS):
                generation[x][y] = c

    # Creates a random grid based on the slider value.
    def random_grid(self):
        self.next_iteration = False
        self.init_gen(next_generation, COLOR_DEAD)
        self.percentage_zero = list(itertools.repeat(0,
                                                     (100 - self.slider_random.get())))
        self.percentage_one = list(itertools.repeat(1,
                                                    (self.slider_random.get())))
        # print(self.percentage_zero)
        # print(self.percentage_one)
        for row in range(X_CELLS):
            for col in range(Y_CELLS):
                next_generation[row][col] = random.choice(self.percentage_zero + self.percentage_one)
                # print(next_generation[row][col])

    # Drawing the cells, color black or blue at location (x,y).
    def draw_cell(self, x, y, c):
        pos = (int(x * CELL_SIZE + CELL_SIZE / 2),
               int(y * CELL_SIZE + CELL_SIZE / 2))
        # pygame.draw.rect(screen, colors[c], pygame.Rect(x * CELL_SIZE, y * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE-1, CELL_SIZE-1))
        # pygame.draw.circle(screen, colors[c], pos, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE) #Weird form, can also be used instead of rectangles
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, colors[c], pos, 5, 0)

    # Updating the cells in the current generation.
    def update_gen(self):
        global current_generation
        for y in range(Y_CELLS):
            for x in range(X_CELLS):
                c = next_generation[x][y]
                self.draw_cell(x, y, c)
        current_generation = list(next_generation)

    # Activate a living cell.
    def activate_living_cell(self, x, y):
        global next_generation
        next_generation[x][y] = COLOR_ALIVE

    # Deactivate a living cell.
    def deactivate_living_cell(self, x, y):
        global next_generation
        next_generation[x][y] = COLOR_DEAD

    # Function to check neighbor cells.
    def check_cells(self, x, y):
        # Check the edges.
        if (x < 0) or (y < 0):
            return 0
        if (x >= X_CELLS) or (y >= Y_CELLS):
            return 0
        if current_generation[x][y] == COLOR_ALIVE:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def check_cell_neighbors(self, row_index, col_index):
        # Get the number of alive cells surrounding the current cell.
        num_alive_neighbors = 0
        num_alive_neighbors += self.check_cells(row_index - 1, col_index - 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.check_cells(row_index - 1, col_index)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.check_cells(row_index - 1, col_index + 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.check_cells(row_index, col_index - 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.check_cells(row_index, col_index + 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.check_cells(row_index + 1, col_index - 1)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.check_cells(row_index + 1, col_index)
        num_alive_neighbors += self.check_cells(row_index + 1, col_index + 1)
        return num_alive_neighbors

    # Rules:
    # 1 Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies, as if by underpopulation.
    # 2 Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives on to the next generation.
    # 3 Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies, as if by overpopulation.
    # 4 Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
    def create_next_gen(self):
        for y in range(Y_CELLS):
            for x in range(X_CELLS):
                n = self.check_cell_neighbors(x, y)  # Number of neighbors.
                c = current_generation[x][y]  # Current cell (either dead or alive).
                if c == COLOR_ALIVE:
                    if (n < 2):  # Rule number 1.
                        next_generation[x][y] = COLOR_DEAD
                    elif (n > 3):  # Rule number 3.
                        next_generation[x][y] = COLOR_DEAD
                    else:  # Rule number 2.
                        next_generation[x][y] = COLOR_ALIVE
                elif c == COLOR_DEAD:
                    if (n == 3):  # Rule number 4.
                        next_generation[x][y] = COLOR_ALIVE
                    else:
                        next_generation[x][y] = COLOR_DEAD
#Problem: first counting, then next iteration.

    # Defines button and mouse clicks.
    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Turns the mouse position into a position in the grid.
            posn = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x = int(posn[0] / CELL_SIZE)
            y = int(posn[1] / CELL_SIZE)
            # Pressing quit --> quit the game.
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.game_over = True
            # Pressing the left mouse button to activate or deactivate a cell.
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if next_generation[x][y] == COLOR_DEAD:
                        self.activate_living_cell(x, y)
                    else:
                        self.deactivate_living_cell(x, y)
            # Keeping the right mouse button pressed activates drawing mode.
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and event.buttons[2]:
                self.activate_living_cell(x, y)

            # Define the keyboard key presses for q, space, a, s, r.
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # Quit the game.
                if event.unicode == 'q':
                    self.game_over = True
                    print("q")
                # Next iteration - manually.
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    self.create_next_gen()
                    print("keypress")
                # Next iteration - automated.
                elif event.unicode == 'a':  # a to automate the iterations.
                    self.next_iteration = True
                    print("a")
                # Stop the automated iterations.
                elif event.unicode == 's':
                    self.next_iteration = False
                    print("s")
                # Empty the grid.
                elif event.unicode == 'r':
                    self.next_iteration = False
                    self.init_gen(next_generation, COLOR_DEAD)
                    print("r")

    # Runs the game loop
    def run(self):
        while not self.game_over:
            self.handle_events()
            if self.next_iteration:
                self.create_next_gen()
            self.update_gen()
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.fps_clock.tick(FPS_MAX)
            self.root.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GAME = GameOfLife()
    GAME.run()
```

Comment: I found this comment somewhere, which describes my problem: The problem is that you are modifying the grid in the same pass as you are evaluating what needs to change. Each time you change a cell, you are affecting the outcome of all future tests in the same pass that border that cell.  Can someone help fix this? :)

Comment: Anyone? I really have no idea how to fix this. I have this statement in the code:      current_generation = list(next_generation)  , but it's not working at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to deep copy `next_generation` to `current_generation`. But

> ```
> current_generation = list(next_generation)
> ```

doesn't do what you expect it to do, since the elements of `next_generation` are a list, too.

To deep copy a list of where each element is a list of numbers (objects won't be copied) you've to:

```py
current_generation = [list(e) for e in next_generation]
```

or

```py
current_generation = [[i for i in j] for j in next_generation]
```

or

```py
current_generation = [e[:] for e in next_generation]
```

Since there is a nested loop in the method `GameOfLife.update_gen`, the issue can be solved by an simple assignment, too:

```
class GameOfLife:

    # [...]

    # Updating the cells in the current generation.
    def update_gen(self):
        global current_generation
        for y in range(Y_CELLS):
            for x in range(X_CELLS):
                c = next_generation[x][y]
                self.draw_cell(x, y, c)
                current_generation[x][y] = next_generation[x][y] # assign element by element
```

---

There is a further issue, when the animation is running and the game is manipulated by the mouse. When the mouse is pressed, then `next_generation` is changed by either `.activate_living_cell` or `.deactivate_living_cell`.
But after that `next_generation` is recalculated by the data in `current_generation`.

> ```
> while not self.game_over:
>      self.handle_events()       # change "next_generation" by click
>      if self.next_iteration:
>          self.create_next_gen() # compute "next_generation" from "current_generation"
>      self.update_gen()          # copy "current_generation" from "next_generation"
> ```

The issue can be solved with ease. Consider that when the game is manipulated by the mouse, the content of `current_generation` and `next_generation` is equal.

Either change `current_generation` instead of `next_generation` or update `current_generation` after the manipulation:

```py
def handle_events(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # [...]        

        # Pressing the left mouse button to activate or deactivate a cell.
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if next_generation[x][y] == COLOR_DEAD:
                    self.activate_living_cell(x, y)
                else:
                   self.deactivate_living_cell(x, y)
                self.update_gen() # <----------------------------
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment. I have changed this, and now it works. I can press random, and it works as intented.  However, I cannot draw in the grid, or manually activate cells in the grid anymore. Why did this break?

Comment: If I change def activate_living_cell  and def deactivate_living_cell into the next_generation[x][y] = COLOR_ALIVE  and next_generation[x][y] = COLOR_DEAD,  it works again. I don't understand why, as I don't want to draw on the next_Generation right?

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your effort! I get your second point, but thats only relevant if I want users to be able to activate/draw cells when the game is running right?